# bash standard output can not be redirected into file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe, io-redirection

I am reading 'advanced bash script', in Chapter 31, there is a problem. I can not figure it out.

`tail -f /var/log/msg | grep 'error' >> logfile`

Why is there  nothing to output into logfile?
can you offer me an explanation?
thank you in advance

Comment: because there are no lines in the tail of /var/log/msg that contain the string 'error'?  `tail -f` shows you what's being written to the file now, and `grep` filters out only the lines that match, so if there are no lines that match, nothing will be output.

Comment: @MarkReed, yes, there are lines in the file 'msg'

Comment: @ruanhao: There has to be `error` text in last 10 lines otherwise `tail -f` just waits for new logs to appear.

Comment: @anubhava, i have do `echo "hello error" >> /var/log/msg`, but there is no reflect, and <<advanced bash script>> says it is right that there should be no any output redirected into log file. i just can not understand why.

Comment: `echo "hello error" >> /var/log/msg` may not work as you don't have permissions to write into tat file.

Comment: @anubhava, hello, it is just an example, i have permission, i can write, it is how linux pipe works, just i don't know why this way

Comment: btw there is no pipe in `echo "hello error" >> /var/log/msg`

Comment: Until *enough* matching lines are accumulated by `grep`, which uses buffering, nothing is written to the log file.

Comment: @anubhava, then, so please assume that there are some lines in 'msg' file

Comment: presence of some lines doesn't matter. What matters is if there is a string `error` in last 10 lines (or in new lines coming to log file)

Comment: hello, @chepner, your judge is right, i just did `for i in $( seq 1 10000 ); do echo "error" >> msg; done`  stuff shows up in logfile, but not all lines. but, can i flush? how can i flush?

Comment: it is ok to use `tail -f msg | grep --line-buffered 'error' >> logfile`, but i still wonder why there seems no buffering when 'grep' directly outputs to stdout?

Comment: My guess is that `grep` can only distinguish between writing to the terminal and writing to not-a-terminal, so it errors on the side of "show stuff now" for terminals and "buffer for more efficient writes" for non-terminals. It's up to you to tell `grep` when a file is actually a pipe to a program that writes to the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @chepner comments, `grep` is using a larger buffer (perhaps 4k or more) to buffer its stdout.  Most of the standard utilities do this when piping or redirecting to a file.  They typically only switch to line-buffered mode when outputting directly to the terminal.

You can use the [`stdbuf` utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) to force `grep` to do line buffering of its output:

```
tail -f /var/log/msg | stdbuf -oL grep 'error' >> logfile
```

As an easily observable demonstration of this effect, you can try the following two commands:

```
for ((i=0;;i++)); do echo $i; sleep 0.001; done | grep . | cat
```

and

```
for ((i=0;;i++)); do echo $i; sleep 0.001; done | stdbuf -oL grep . | cat
```

In the first command, the output from `grep .` (i.e. match all lines) be buffered going into the pipe to `cat`.  On mine the buffer appears to be about 4k.  You will see the ascending numbers output in `chunks` as the buffer gets filled and then flushed.

In the second command, `grep`'s output into the pipe to `cat` is line-buffered, so you should see terminal output for every line, i.e. more-or-less continuous output.

Comment: thank you very mush for you answer. i think you are right. it is `grep` that plays the trick. it does not use buffer only when stdout is terminal.